# Maven exclude language files from jasig CAS

Tags: maven, cas

I searched to disable all languages and set the default language to english. So that only english is available. But i think there is no possibility to do this in jasig CAS.

So i'm trying to remove all language files from the final .war file of my jasig CAS build.

Her is my pom.xml file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>lu.ion.cas</groupId>
<artifactId>cas-ion</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cas-ion Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <cas.version>3.5.1</cas.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ja-sig</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>cas-ion</warName>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/messages_*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The part who is supposed to remove those files:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/messages_*.properties</exclude>
</excludes>
```

But those files are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `webResources` element. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#webresourcesexclude

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>path_to_messages</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>messages_*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  Maven War plugin Overlays described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

In this case pom is like this:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
    <overlays>
        <overlay>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/messages_*.properties</exclude>        
            </excludes>
        </overlay>
    </overlays>
</configuration>
```

If you want include a language, add another overlay like this:

```
<overlay>                           
<groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
<artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>                          
<includes>
    <include>WEB-INF/classes/messages_en.properties</include>                       
</includes>
```